# AWS ELB : indicates in service but no traffic passing through

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-opsworks

I have an ELB configured to balance traffic between two rails application layers in Opsworks.

Both EC2 rails app instances are hittable using their direct IP addresses.

```
<instance1_ip/health
<instance2_ip/health
```

Both instances are shown as "InService" in the ELB Instance Tab.

When I attempt to use the DNS name of the ELB to hit them nothing happens, the browser simply hangs and times out.

`<elb dns name>/health` .... times out.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the security group of ELB allows inbound HTTP/HTTPS traffic from browser's IP?

Comment: ARG! that was it, bone head move by me. Please post as answer so I can reward you and help future searchers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the security group of ELB allows inbound HTTP/HTTPS traffic from browser's IP.

Comment: This is weird, because if the instance's SG is not configured correctly, the ELB health check would have timeout and ELB should not report the instances as being "In Service" ....

Comment: Right, but it sounds like this was the ELB SG not allowing inbound traffic.